# PhantomJS + Meteor (Spiderable) + Heroku problems

Tags: javascript, heroku, meteor, phantomjs

So I am trying to get spiderable playing nice on heroku yet when I do

```
curl [WEBSITE]?_escaped_fragment_=
```

I am not getting the content.  I have it working in development and am getting the following error server-side when I try curling in production:

```
app[web.1]: spiderable: phantomjs failed: { [Error: Command failed: /bin/bash: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/phantomjs/main/node_modules/phantomjs-sun/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: Permission denied
app[web.1]: /bin/bash: line 0: exec: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/phantomjs/main/node_modules/phantomjs-sun/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: cannot execute: Permission denied
app[web.1]: ] killed: false, code: 126, signal: null }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the best bet is to go ahead and get the binary for your instance:

[PhantomJS + Meteor (Spiderable) + Heroku problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197434/phantomjs-meteor-spiderable-heroku-problems)

```
heroku run bash -a  <app name>
```

and then from within your app web instance:

```
curl -O -L 'http://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2'
tar -xvjf phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

You can then go into that directory to see if it will run correctly.  If it does, then you should pester the buildpack people into adding phantom, or branch theirs to include it making sure your buildpack sets the path correctly.

Alternative 1:

Spiderable appear to pull in phantomjs possible using this package: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/phantomjs

Perhaps you can try doing an:

```
mrt install phantomjs
```

from within the meteorite project.

Alternative 2:

Go remote by using this package https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/spiderable-remote

Comment: When I try the tar command I receive the following error:

  `bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
  tar: Child returned status 2
  tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

I have previously been using the first alternate which works fine locally.  
Also tried the 2nd alternate and it had the same problems of not reaching the Ajax loaded content.  

The reason I needed it was for facebook sharing.  Just ended up using their API to define parameters of share instead of having their crawlers find it.

Comment: I updated the command, phantom.js had moved the download file.  You can get the url from their download page of course: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: received the following error when I tried the main option:
tar: phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: ok, I realize phantomjs.org was redirecting the link.  I changed the answer above to use the -L option, which follows redirects.

Comment: So I got it when I defined all the variables needed in the buildpacks and started with a fresh heroku app, thank you!

Comment: Here's the thing, when you go with route 1, and if it works while you have the bash setting up, then you know that it's not Heroku that's causing the problem.  You should now file an issue with the package maintainer for the Heroku Buildpack for PhantomJS, and ask them to include this version of Phantomjs, ie the 64bit.